# Are there any other IM clients other than empathy and pidgin that support google talk?

Tags: empathy, pidgin, instant-messaging

As stated above. I need something similar to Google talk and it should be more stable than empathy. I dont like Pidgin, for it's interface makes it difficult to set statuses more often... Please let me have the entire list of IM clients that run on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Google Talk uses the [XMPP (Jabber)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) standardized protocol; the following is a complete list of the IM clients in the Ubuntu repositories which *should* support Google Talk.

**Please note** that some of these are command-line (console) clients; I have highlighted the ones I know are graphical (or GUI) in bold:

```
ayttm - Universal instant messaging client
barnowl - A curses-based tty Jabber, IRC, AIM  and Zephyr client
centerim - A text-mode multi-protocol instant messenger client
ekg2 - instant messenger and IRC client for UNIX systems
finch - text-based multi-protocol instant messaging client
freetalk - console based Jabber client
gajim - Jabber client written in PyGTK
jwchat - a full featured, web-based Jabber chat client
kadu - Gadu-Gadu/XMPP client for X11
kopete - instant messaging and chat application
licq - multi-protocol instant messaging client (base files)
licq-plugin-jabber - Jabber plug-in for Licq
mcabber - small Jabber (XMPP) console client
pidgin - graphical multi-protocol instant messaging client for X
psi - Jabber client using Qt
psi-plus - Qt-based jabber client (basic version)
qutim - multi-protocol instant messenger
sendxmpp - commandline XMPP (jabber) utility
tkabber - GUI client for XMPP (Jabber) instant messaging protocol
```

Answer (score 1):

Well those 2 are the best, but there are others like Goober Instant Messenger.

KOPETE is quite good to, not sure if it suports gtalk to be honest.

Comment: Why not a Google messenger? I wonder why they went to the 'cloud' and emphasize using the web browser... empathy has mood swings. It connects to gtalk when it likes to.

Comment: because it is better on the web. you open your browser, log in and then you can minimize it and you get popups like you would be on a real messenger. all with no additional programs.

Comment: Do I get popups? Maybe only on google chrome...